# Would it be appropriate to upgrade [synonymizer] badge from bronze to silver?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, tag-synonyms

I noticed that it is quite difficult to earn the [synonymizer] badge, and very few indeed earned it on SO.

Would it be appropriate to upgrade this badge from bronze to silver?

Comment: Rage against the machine and take the power back, i.e. the synoym system is so broken anyway the entire system should be removed, fiddling around the edges isn't going to make a difference.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - would you care to elaborate? I'm not sure I follow...